# Does the MongoDB C# driver support Joins of this manner?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have two classes `Person` and `Animal`

```
using System;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
namespace MongoTesting.Documents
{
    public class Person
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public Guid PersonId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

        public Guid PetId { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;

        public string Name { get; set; } = "Person";
    }
}

using System;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
namespace MongoTesting.Documents
{
    public class Animal
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public Guid AnimalId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

        public bool IsMammal { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; } = "Animal";
    }
}
```

Which are serialized into `IMongoCollection`s

```
public IMongoCollection<Person> PersonCollection { get; set; }
public IMongoCollection<Animal> AnimalCollection { get; set; }
...
PersonCollection = Database.GetCollection<Person>("PersonCollection");
AnimalCollection = Database.GetCollection<Animal>("AnimalCollection");
```

Using the C# 2.7.0 MongoDB .Net driver and the MongoDB 3.4 mongod server daemon.

I am trying to write a specific type of query given this setup, specifically the one in the SSCCE below

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using MongoTesting.Documents;
using MongoTesting.DatabaseInterface;

using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace MongoTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MongoInterface _mongo = new MongoInterface();
            _mongo.Open();

            //CreateDocuments(_mongo);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Total Persons: " + _mongo.PersonCollection.CountDocuments(Builders<Person>.Filter.Empty));
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Total Animals: " + _mongo.AnimalCollection.CountDocuments(Builders<Animal>.Filter.Empty));

            var peopleWithMammalianPetsQuery =
                from person in _mongo.PersonCollection.AsQueryable()
                join animal in _mongo.AnimalCollection.AsQueryable() on person.PetId equals animal.AnimalId
                where animal.IsMammal
                select person;

            var peopleWithMammalianPets = peopleWithMammalianPetsQuery.ToList();
            peopleWithMammalianPets.ForEach(person => { Console.Out.WriteLine("Person: " + person.Name); });

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void CreateDocuments(MongoInterface _mongo)
        {
            Animal dog = new Animal() { IsMammal = true, Description = "Dog" };
            Animal cat = new Animal() { IsMammal = true, Description = "Cat" };
            Animal bird = new Animal() { IsMammal = false, Description = "Bird" };
            Animal snake = new Animal() { IsMammal = false, Description = "Snake" };

            Person bob = new Person() { PetId = dog.AnimalId, Name = "Bob" };
            Person sue = new Person() { PetId = cat.AnimalId, Name = "Sue" };
            Person sam = new Person() { PetId = bird.AnimalId, Name = "Sam" };
            Person eve = new Person() { PetId = snake.AnimalId, Name = "Eve" };

            _mongo.PersonCollection.InsertMany(new List<Person>() { bob, sue, sam, eve });
            _mongo.AnimalCollection.InsertMany(new List<Animal>() { dog, cat, bird, snake });
        }
    }
}
```

Where `MongoInterface` represents a class which can connect to the MongoDB server, get access to the `IMongoDatabase`, and manipulate `PersonCollection` and `AnimalCollection`.

---

My specific issue with the code above, is that, when ran the following exception is thrown during the execution of the `peopleWithMammalianPetsQuery`.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in 
>   MongoDB.Driver.dll
>   Additional information: $project or $group does not support {document}.

I have searched around and I cannot find something the exactly duplicates this issue and solves it. There are many reports of the exception message though they all seem to differ in the usage which produced it (even some seem to have been fixed). I have also seen multiple posts showing very similar code (specifically a `join`) working without issue.

**How can I perform the query described above?**

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://gist.github.com/Skamiplan/45a709939dcb04795a77b3937f5f797c) could help you along a bit, by generically building an aggregate with lookups which you can append with another match stage with IsMammal to suit your needs.